# Calendar not showing events in Agenda

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I'm using the React Native Calendars library to call an API and display the events in that API. The events in the eventsArray are not being displayed to the agenda of the calendar. Instead, it's showing a blank page.I am calling an api using redux toolkit.and the eventsArray is not empty it contain 4 objects which has name,title,no

Here's the code I'm using:

```
const Calendar = ({eventsArray}) => {
  const [items, setItems] = React.useState({});
  const currentDate = moment().format('YYYY-MM-DD');

  const loadItems = day => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      for (let i = -15; i < 85; i++) {
        const time = day.timestamp + i * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000;
        const strTime = timeToString(time);

        if (!items[strTime]) {
          items[strTime] = [];
          const daysEvent = _.filter(
            eventsArray,
            event => event.hearingdate == strTime,
          );
          if (daysEvent) {
            daysEvent.forEach(event => {
              items[strTime].push({
                name: event.clientname,
                caseNumber: event.casenumber,
                court: event.courtname,
                height: Math.max(10, Math.floor(Math.random() * 150)),
                day: strTime,
              });
            });
          } else {
            items[strTime].push({
              name: null,
              caseNumber: null,
              court: null,
              height: Math.max(10, Math.floor(Math.random() * 150)),
              day: strTime,
            });
          }
        }
      }
      const newItems = {};
      Object.keys(items).forEach(key => {
        newItems[key] = items[key];
      });
      setItems(newItems);
    }, 500);
  };
  const renderItem = (item, firstItemInDay) => {
    return (
      <>
        {firstItemInDay ? (
          <View>
            <View style={styles.firstItemContainer}>
              <Text>
                {moment(item.day, 'YYYY-MM-DD').format('DD')}{' '}
                {moment(item.day, 'YYYY-MM-DD').format('MMM').substring(0, 3)}
              </Text>
            </View>
            {item && item.name ? (
              <TouchableOpacity style={styles.item}>
                <Card>
                  <Card.Content>
                    <View/>
          <TouchableOpacity style={styles.item}>
            <Card>
              <Card.Content>
                <View/>
                <View>
                  <Label text={item.name} />
                </View>
                <View style={{marginTop: 8}}>
                  <Label text={item.caseNumber} />
                </View>
                <View style={{marginTop: 3}}>
                  <Label text={item.court}  />
                </View>
              </Card.Content>
            </Card>
          </TouchableOpacity>
        )}
      </>
    );
  };

  return (
    <View >
      <Agenda
        items={items}
        loadItemsForMonth={loadItems}
        selected={moment().format('YYYY-MM-DD')}
        minDate={'2022-01-01'}
        maxDate={'2025-01-01'}
        renderEmptyDate={renderEmptyDate}
        refreshControl={null}
        showClosingKnob={true}
        refreshing={false}
        renderItem={renderItem}
        renderDay={(day, item) => {
          return <View />;
        }}
      />
    </View>
  );
};
```